# Filtering array by value from deeply nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I'm trying to filter posts by category for a blog that uses React.
Here is what the data looks like:

```js
const posts = [
  {
    "categories": [
      {
        "title": "tag1"
      },
      {
        "title": "tag2"
      },
      {
        "title": "tag3"
      }
    ],
    "title": "First post",
    // more stuff here
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      {
        "title": "tag2"
      },
      {
        "title": "tag3"
      },
      {
        "title": "tag4"
      },
      {
        "title": "tag5"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Second post"
    // more stuff here
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      {
        "title": "tag1"
      },
      {
        "title": "tag3"
      },
      {
        "title": "tag4"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Third post"
    // more stuff here
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      {
        "title": "tag1"
      },
      {
        "title": "tag2"
      },
      {
        "title": "tag4"
      },
      {
        "title": "tag5"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Fourth post"
    // more stuff here
  }
]
```

I have a piece of state called filter that updated from a `<select>` menu, which looks like this:
`const [filter, setFilter] = useState('all');`

How would I write the rest of this code block?

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (filter !== 'all') {
    // Not sure what to do here
}
}, [])
```

Not sure if I use filter on the first array, or do I keep using filter all the way down? I've tried a bunch of things, but haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't need to be inside an effect, you can just filter in the component. Also, what's in the select? Is it tags?

Comment: @Nick is right, if you're array is in the state, then what you need is a [selector](https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store/selectors) which filters the array based on a category instead of an effect, but if the array is in the component then you can just filter the array in the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can filter an object like that:

```js
const posts = [
  {
    "categories": [
      {
        "title": "tag1"
      },
      {
        "title": "tag2"
      },
      {
        "title": "tag3"
      }
    ],
    "title": "First post"
  },
  {
    "categories": [
      {
        "title": "tag2"
      },
      {
        "title": "tag3"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Second Post"
  }
];

const filter = "tag1";

const filtered = posts.filter(post => {
  return post.categories.some(cat => cat.title === filter)
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Now in a functional component, there's really no need to use an effect, this is simple run on your state every time the component is rendered:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("all");

  const filtered =
    filter === "all"
      ? posts
      : posts.filter((post) => {
          return post.categories.some((cat) => cat.title === filter);
        });

  return <>Render stuff here</>
}
```

If your component updates a lot and the filter is running too much, you can look into using a `useMemo` hook to memoize the value until the `filter` changes.

Comment: Thanks Nick! That makes a lot of sense. I've got it working now 